# Flutter: Application's locale is not supported by all of its localization delegates

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, internationalization

Hello I am trying add BottomNavigationBar in flutter app but when i run project error occures :

```
A MaterialLocalizations delegate that supports the ka_GE locale was not found
```

This is my app delegates:

```
  supportedLocales: [
    const Locale('en', 'US'),
    const Locale('ka', 'GE'),
    const Locale('ru', 'RU'),
  ],
  localizationsDelegates: [
    const InfosLocalizationsDelegate(),
    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate
  ],
  locale: Locale('ka')
```

This is Custom LocalizationsDelegate:

```
class CLocalizationsDelegate
    extends LocalizationsDelegate<CLocalizations> {
  const CLocalizationsDelegate();

  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) =>
      ['en', 'ka', 'ru'].contains(locale.languageCode);

  @override
  Future<CLocalizations> load(Locale locale) async {
    CLocalizations localizations = new CLocalizations(locale);
    await localizations.load();
    print("Load ${locale.languageCode}");
    return localizations;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReload(CLocalizationsDelegate old) => false;
}
```

Yeah I know that the problem is 'ka' because MaterialLocalizations doesn't not supports it  but I have to solve that problem, so guys can you help me out?

Comment: You have to make your own MaterializationLocalizations for `ka`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can implement your custom `MaterialLocalizations` delegate

```
class MaterialLocalizationKaDelegate extends LocalizationsDelegate<MaterialLocalizations> {
  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) {
    return locale.countryCode == "GE" && locale.languageCode == "ka";
  }

  @override
  Future<MaterialLocalizations> load(Locale locale) async {
    return MaterialLocalizationKa();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReload(Foo old) {
    return false;
  }
}

class MaterialLocalizationKa extends MaterialLocalizations {
  // TODO: implement KA localization yourself
}
```

Comment: Kindly guide how to make use of this code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57902361/flutter-app-crashes-building-the-appbar-with-multi-language-using-i18n-jetbrains

Comment: Can I just ignore this error in case my app has not been internationalized yet?

Answer (score 54):

Addig ***GlobalCupertinoLocalizations*** too to the localizationsDelegates also saves the problem.

```
return MaterialApp(
  localizationsDelegates: const [
    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
  ],
  // ...
);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This was the perfect answer. GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate, was missing in my code.

Comment: This is should be the correct answer. +1 vote. Thank you so much.

Comment: Right, `GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate`, was missing in my code too. Great answer.

Comment: This should be the correct answer, thanks :)