# Flutter app crashes building the AppBar with multi language using i18n Jetbrains plugin's boilerplate

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, internationalization, jetbrains-ide

I'm using Flutter i18n plugin for Android Studio following the [official documentation](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10128-flutter-i18n).

I added the few configuration line needed to a minimal app that displays a String:

```dart
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [S.delegate],
      supportedLocales: S.delegate.supportedLocales,
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
//      appBar: AppBar(
//        title: Text("Hard-coded English string"),
//      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(S.of(context).string_that_should_be_internationalized),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is working (the string is actually translated to my phone system language). But a warning is thrown at every call to build:

```
Warning: This application's locale, it_, is not supported by all of its
localization delegates.
> A MaterialLocalizations delegate that supports the it_ locale was not found.
```

Despite `S.delegate.supportedLocales` being `[en_, it_]` and all arb file being correctly configured.

I can make the `Scaffold` body arbitrarily complicated and the behavior remains the same (i18n works with warning). But if I add a simple `AppBar` (even if the widged does not require translation) to the `Scaffold` the whole application crashes. (E.g. uncommenting in the snippet above)

Abstract of the error:

```
I/flutter (11411): No MaterialLocalizations found.
I/flutter (11411): AppBar widgets require MaterialLocalizations to be provided by a Localizations widget ancestor.
I/flutter (11411): Localizations are used to generate many different messages, labels,and abbreviations which are used
I/flutter (11411): by the material library.
I/flutter (11411): To introduce a MaterialLocalizations, either use a  MaterialApp at the root of your application to
I/flutter (11411): include them automatically, or add a Localization widget with a MaterialLocalizations delegate.
I/flutter (11411): The specific widget that could not find a MaterialLocalizations ancestor was:
I/flutter (11411):   AppBar
```

The framework is complaining about my `AppBar` not having a *Localizations widget ancestor*. But it actually have because it's inside a `MaterialApp`. No clue on how to solve this mystery.

[Full log](https://pastebin.com/hU48e2cS)

EDIT
Another weird thing i just discovered: running the same exact app in `--release` mode gets rid of all the errors and warnings; everything is correctly translated including the `AppBar`.
Still wondering why it crashes in `--debug` mode.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is not about the boilerplate code or configuration.

The meaning of the error is that there is no support for the language "it_" for the "default system strings". (In particular it crashes due to some default tooltip of the AppBar -> that's why it is crashing if an `AppBar` is displayed).

As reported [in this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53177878/flutter-applications-locale-is-not-supported-by-all-of-its-localization-delega) you can solve the issue by implementing your own `LocalizationsDelegate`.

## Full fix

```dart
class MaterialLocalizationItDelegate extends LocalizationsDelegate<MaterialLocalizations> {
  /// Here list supported country and language codes
  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) => locale.languageCode == "it";
  /// Here create an instance of your [MaterialLocalizations] subclass
  @override
  Future<MaterialLocalizations> load(Locale locale) async => MaterialLocalizationIt();
  @override
  bool shouldReload(_) => false;
}

class MaterialLocalizationIt extends MaterialLocalizations {
  // alt-enter on intellij and implement many overrides (somthing like 57)
}
```

And then append your delegate to the list of delegates:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [S.delegate, MaterialLocalizationItDelegate()],  // <- append here
      supportedLocales: S.delegate.supportedLocales,
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

## Quick fix

An hasty way to check if this will work for you before implementing the 57 overrides.
Copy exactly this code:

```dart
class FallbackLocalizationDelegate extends LocalizationsDelegate<MaterialLocalizations> {
  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) => true;
  @override
  Future<MaterialLocalizations> load(Locale locale) async => DefaultMaterialLocalizations();
  @override
  bool shouldReload(_) => false;
}
```

The above class claim to support all locales (`isSupported(Locale locale) => true`) and simply returns the default en_US locale.
Finally add this to your list of delegates.

```dart
localizationsDelegates: [S.delegate, FallbackLocalizationDelegate()],  // <- append here
```

This quick fix will set all the default system strings to English, but your "custom" localization should work.

Comment: Works like a charm with easy_localization 3.0.0. Quick fix also gets the job done easily! Thanks a ton..

Comment: Quick fix fixed issue for easy_localization. thanks

Comment: quickfix save me thanks getting unsupport local on sanskrit language after adding quickfix work like charm

Comment: I had to repeat the quickfix twice (once for `MaterialLocalizations` and once for `CupertinoLocalizations`) but it finally allowed me to run the app in Welsh ("cy"). Steps were: 1. Create two dart files 2. In each file copy the quickfix and give them unique names (mine were `FallbackLocalizationDelegateMaterial`, `FallbackLocalizationDelegateCupertino`). 3. in the cupertino rename usages of `MaterialLocalizations` with `CupertinoLocalizations`, and `DefaultMaterialLocalizations` to `DefaultCupertinoLocalizations`. 4. include both files in `localizationsDelegates` as in the example

Answer (score 0):

also use can DefaultMaterialLocalizations instead of MaterialLocalizations and override aren't really except you need too
check this for more details https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/localizationsDelegates.html