# GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate Does not Support Chinese

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-intl, flutter-localizations

It seems `GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate` does not support the `zh` Locale ***(Chinese)***.

Is it really necessary adding `GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate` before other locales works?

I get this error each time I run the app without adding the ***GlobalCupertinoLocalizations*** delegate:

[image]

Could this be a bug in Flutter? because according to the official Docs [HERE](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_localizations/GlobalMaterialLocalizations-class.html) the `GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate` does have support for ***zh - Chinese***

The full source code is available [HERE](https://github.com/Joshuaerinosho/flutter_samples/blob/c9e32cc1c79a867a8d12c9a248726c9c22f093e3/multiple_locale/lib/main.dart#L16)

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the next delegate solves the problem:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FallbackLocalizationDelegate extends LocalizationsDelegate<MaterialLocalizations> {
  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) => true;

  @override
  Future<MaterialLocalizations> load(Locale locale) async => const DefaultMaterialLocalizations();

  @override
  bool shouldReload(old) => false;
}
```

Source: [Flutter app crashes building the AppBar with multi language using i18n Jetbrains plugin's boilerplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57902361/flutter-app-crashes-building-the-appbar-with-multi-language-using-i18n-jetbrains)