# Another exception was thrown: Warning: This application's locale, om, is not supported by all of its localization delegates

Tags: flutter, dart

I have added new new support for new language to my own flutter app locale and I have got the above exception  . Could you you give me direction

Comment: i found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53177878/flutter-applications-locale-is-not-supported-by-all-of-its-localization-delega) which is similar with yours, might be helpful

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation ,!. I have seen it but I can't understand the answer  of that post.

Answer (score 0):

Which Locale have you added and which package are you using for localisation ?

Comment: Thank you !. I have used flutter_localization . I follow the steps here  https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/accessibility-and-internationalization/internationalization. And want to add new language that is not supported by MaterialLocalization  .

Answer (score 0):

After I build in release , I understand that it has no effect and it is warning to let us know the specified locale is not supported by MaterialLocalization.

So , It has no bug on building app .